# indexing suggestions using analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I'm trying to figure out how to index suggestion without splitting my text using a delimiter and storing it in the `CompletionField`:

```
 List<string> inputs = new List<string>() {
                facility.City,
                facility.State,
                facility.ZipCode
            };
            inputs.AddRange(facility.Name.Split(' '));
            inputs.AddRange(facility.Address.Split(' '));
            inputs.AddRange(facilityType.Description.Split(' '));
            var completionField = new CompletionField()
            {
                Input = inputs.AsEnumerable<string>()
            };
            return completionField;
```

This isn't a optimal way of doing this because, I would rather let the analyzer handle this as oppose to doing this and then indexing it. Is there a way to send the entire text to Elastic and let Elastic analyze the text and store in in the completionfield on indexing or something else?

**Updated**

I've my code to index the entire text and to use the default analyzer however, this is what was index and the analyzer isn't breaking the text up

```
"suggest": {
            "input": [
              "Reston",
              "Virginia",
              "20190",
              "Facility 123456",
              "22100 Sunset Hills Rd suite 150*"
            ]
          },
```

My code:

```
 List<string> inputs = new List<string>() {
                facility.City,
                facility.State,
                facility.ZipCode
            };
            inputs.Add(facility.Name);
            inputs.Add(facility.Address);
            if (facility.Description != null && facility.Description != "")
            {
                inputs.Add(facility.Description);
            }
            var completionField = new CompletionField()
            {
                Input = inputs.AsEnumerable<string>()
            };
            return completionField;
```

My mapping for the property:

```
 "suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "analyzer": "simple",
            "preserve_separators": true,
            "preserve_position_increments": true,
            "max_input_length": 50
          },
```

But, yet it's not breaking up my *input*.

Answer (score 1):

Just send all the text in input and specify a custom analyzer that uses  the whitespace tokenizer and nothing else

EDIT
First add the analyzer

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type":      "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc" : {
        "properties" : {
            "suggest" : {
                "type" : "completion",
                "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
            },
            "title" : {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then specify it on suggest field

Comment: if I dont specify a custom analyzer...would it use the default `simple`?

Comment: Yes it would use the simple analyzer by default for suggest field

Comment: I've updated the code above. I tried to use the simple analyzer (which is what is being sued by default) however, the text aren't being broken up.

Comment: simple doesn't tokenize you need to specify a custom analyzer (you can override simple analyzer or make it a new analyzer that is up to you). See my edit for how to do this

Comment: `simple doesn't tokenize` I'm a bit confused as the docs said it does `analyzer
The index analyzer to use, defaults to simple. In case you are wondering why we did not opt for the standard analyzer: We try to have easy to understand behaviour here, and if you index the field content At the Drive-in, you will not get any suggestions for a, nor for d (the first non stopword).` [see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html).

Comment: Also, according to the docs Simple Analyzer does tokenize text Also [see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html).

Comment: Ah I see, it might be the preserve_separators. Let me run some tests and get back to you